# How do you host AWS S3 website with a GoDaddy domain?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, dns

I have followed a selection of [tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) on how to set up a static website with Amazon Web Services. However, I am now encountering a few problems when trying to link it to my GoDaddy domain.

- I have created two buckets: `example.com` & `www.example.com`:
  [image: 2 created buckets]
- `www.example.com` redirects to `example.com`:
  [image: www.example.com bucket]
- My `example.com` bucket has a basic webpage:
  [image: example.com bucket]
- The properties are such:
  [image: bucket properties]
- The permissions are such:
  [image]
- My bucket policy is:

  ```
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "s3:GetObject",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```
- Each file is public:
  [image]
- On Route 53, I have created one hosted zone called `example.com`:
  [image: Hosted zones]
- The record sets are such:
  [image: Record sets]
- On GoDaddy I have added the DNS like so:
  [image: GoDaddy Manage DNS]
- I ran `dig +recurse +trace example.com any`:
  [image]
- I pinged the url:

  ```
  [In] :  ping example.com
  .....:  64 bytes from 52.95.149.7: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=55.722 ms
  ```

52.95.149.7 is https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

If I go to `example.com` I get returned with a timeout error (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. If you need more details for diagnosis let me know.

I have tried to protect my privacy as best as I can. Let me know if I have accidentally disclosed anything sensitive or if important information has been censored.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but it seems like ping cannot even find my domain. How long passed between changing the DNS nameservers and being able to access your site? On GoDaddy it says 4-8 hours sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, I don't see anything wrong. One thing to try is using a proxy, because sometimes the DNS doesn't propagate though the internet quickly enough for you to see it..

Something like https://kproxy.com works. Just punch in your url there.

The other troubleshooting thing I'll do is use https://www.dnsstuff.com/tools to get an idea about how things are routed.

Comment: What the monkey? I put the url into the proxy and it worked, amazing!
Why is this the case? When can I expect it to work normally? I use NordVPN anyways and it doesn't work through that.

Comment: I'm not an expert on DNS but my understanding is that when you request a site through your browser, it asks a name server where to find the site. Some name servers know where to look for your website, but others haven't had a chance to update the new path. I think usually after about 24 hours everything syncs up and you should be able to access it from anywhere. Most times it's faster than that though.

Answer (score 1):

Alias doesn't look alright to me. It supposed to be like the below.

`www.example.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com`

OR

`example.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com`

If you change that, it should work.

Thanks.